# If i am gay should i have to convert my sexual orientation to save myself from the Azaab of Allah?

Tags: homosexuality

I have been fighting with myself for so long to find this question,if i am gay so should i have to change myself cause i have tried a lot to convince myself to have a straight relationship with girl but i can't help it. I need guidance please help me. It's my first time that I'm confronting this just for the answer because i have heard that homosexuality is a sin in islam. if it is sin then how would i fullfil my desires cause I can't do that with a woman.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that your orientation itself is not a sin but it is a sin when you act upon it and do forbidden things. Just like a heterosexual person, who is unmarried or is in separation from his wife, will not get punished for feeling attracted to other women but is sinful only if he indulge in adulatory or do forbidden things.

There are lot of heterosexual people who could not marry due to different issues. It is not excuse for them to indulge in forbidden relation. Just like that you should restrain yourself from indulging in forbidden relationships.

Comment: Many people said it is one's choice like he or she chooses it for himself or herself. But I did not choose it i just felt like I'm attracting to men. It's not my fault, sometimes i think I'm gonna be crazy because of this, I'm struggling a lot with this but i couldn't find help.

Comment: There is debate on why this happens. The brain, our thinking etc is very complicated. Our unconscious mind, early childhood exposures some even say presence of some type of gene etc. can be reason, Allah knows best. But whatever reasons, it is not permitted to indulge in forbidden acts, just like a unmarried straight person who refrain from fornication. I myself is a straight person, married but now living alone for number of years